# Too late to renew my Patent?

Tags: expired-patent

My patent was due for renewal Dec 2019, year 8.  Is there any way I can resurrect it? Thanks in anticipation. Pat.

Comment: Do you mean you missed a fee payment? Patents are not renewable, but there are periodic fees due.

Answer (score 1):

You can petition for acceptance of a late payment - from the [USPTO web site](https://www.uspto.gov/patents-application-process/petitions/19-acceptance-delayed-payment-maintenance-fee-after-expiration) -

> A petition related to acceptance of delayed payment of a maintenance fee after expiration of the patent based on unintentional delay under 35 U.S.C. 41(c) and 37 CFR 1.378 (b) must be accompanied by:
>
> a statement that the delay was unintentional;
>
> payment of the appropriate maintenance fee; and
>
> payment of the petition fee as set forth in 37 CFR 1.17,